# php replace multiple br-tags

Tags: php, regex, line-breaks

I have a string like the one below with multiple br-tags that can occur after \r\n  or after multiple spaces. I'd like to find out when there are 3x br-tags or more right after another (no matter how many \r\n or spaces in between) and replace them for only 2x br-tags.

`<br>
 <br>
<br>
 High Quality Print<br>
<br><br>
 <br><br>
<br>
 Data<br>
<br>
 <br>
<br>`

Expected output:
`<br><br>High Quality Print<br><br>Data<br><br>`

I tried with str_replace but because of various spaces etc. that didn't work and I cannot do regex myself.

Comment: What is your expected output and also show what you've tried?

Comment: `nl2br` have you tried it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
$result = preg_replace('/(?:\s*<br[^>]*>\s*){3,}/s', "<br><br>", $input);
//=> <br><br>High Quality Print<br><br>Data<br><br>
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iD2hH7/2)

Comment: would this work for finding/replacing all kind of <br>,<br >,<br/>? And is there a ' missing in the code?

Comment: See updated answer, it will cover `<br>,<br >,<br/>` etc now.